# Flutter / Firestore - How to run Transaction update on a field inside array of the document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I know I can do this on the top level field of the document. But I'm trying to run a transaction update on a field inside of the array of the document.

Here is how my 'quiz' document is structured:

```
{
  title: '123',
  questions: [
    {
      title: 'question1',
      answers: [
        {
          title: 'answer1',
          votes: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is the code that I'm working with, which fails on the "await tx.update..." because I am passing a string path of 'questions[0].answers[0].votes'. Is it even possible? Or do I have to pull the whole document, update value and replace it?

```
final DocumentReference postRef = Firestore.instance.document('quizes/' + id);
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
  DocumentSnapshot postSnapshot = await tx.get(postRef);
  if (postSnapshot.exists) {
    await tx.update(postRef, <String, dynamic>{'questions[0].answers[0].votes': postSnapshot.data['questions'][0]["answers"][0]["votes"] + 1});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it even possible? Or do I have to pull the whole document, update value and replace it?

In order to update fields inside an array in Firestore, you have to get the array, update the fields you want and then update the document. You can use transactions to do that. Below you will find some details about [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions).

Let me know if this was helpful.